# SQL Is it possible to incorporate a SELECT with a REPLACE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, replace, sql-server-2019

I'm using MS SQL Server 2019

I have a string in a table (tblJobCosts) that has its own ID like this:

```
TextID   jobText
   1     Total Cost for job is £[].  This includes VAT
```

How do I update the value stored in the brackets based on the value from another table?

The end result would look like this:

```
Total Cost for job is £500.  This includes VAT
```

I thought I could incorporate a SELECT with a REPLACE but this does not seem possible:

```
DECLARE @JobNum INT = 123;
  
  UPDATE dbo.JobCosts
  SET jobText = REPLACE (jobText,'[]', 
  SELECT JH.jobCost
  FROM dbo.JobHead AS JH 
   WHERE (JH.JobNo = @JobNum)
   ) AND TextID = 1
```

If I run the above I receive the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Is it possible to incorporate a SELECT with a REPLACE?

Comment: `WITH TableWithUpdates AS (SELECT Table.ExistingColumn, NewStuff = (SELECT val FROM OtherTable WHERE OtherTable.ID = Table...), ... FROM Table) UPDATE TableWithUpdates SET ExistingColumn = NewStuff`. Using CTEs this way rather than the `FROM` clause has the added benefit of allowing easy troubleshooting of what will get updated by executing the `SELECT` independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you cannot call a select statement in the replace function.
I would try something like that:

```
 UPDATE dbo.JobCosts
  SET jobText = REPLACE (jobText,'[]',k.the_cost) from
 
 ( SELECT JH.jobCost as the_cost
   FROM dbo.JobHead AS JH 
   WHERE (JH.JobNo = @JobNum)
   )k 
where TextID = 1
```